# UWP project, I change MediaPlayerElement's property "background", but it don't change, still black

Tags: uwp

In UWP project, I change MediaPlayerElement property "background", but it don't change, still black!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `background` property on a `MediaPlayerElement` does not have the desired effect, because the colors of the media display surface (including the background) are determined by the content that is being played/streamed.

To provide your `MediaPlayerElement` with visual representation for states when the media is not showing (yet) you can use the `PosterSource` property.

`<MediaPlayerElement PosterSource="imageUri" />`

Since the PosterSource expects an ImageSource, you will have to provide a path to an image. If you want just a single color, adding a 1x1 pixel image to you project and providing the path to it as the `imageUri` property should work (I have no environment set up to test this).

From the UWP `PosterSource` docs:

> The PosterSource is displayed in the following situations: When a
>
> - valid source is not set. For example, Source is not set, Source was
>   set to Null, or the source is invalid (as is the case when a MediaFailed event fires).
> - While media is loading. For example, a valid source is set, but the MediaOpened event has not fired yet.
> - When media is streaming to another device.
> - When the media is audio only.

UWP docs sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaPlayerElement?view=winrt-19041#poster-source
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.postersource?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaPlayerElement_PosterSource